# Sandboxing JavaScript using with keyword

Tags: javascript, with-statement, sandbox

I stumbled on this post by Dustin on using the `with` keyword to sandbox some modules:

http://dustindiaz.com/sandboxing-javascript

The actual code snippet is:

```
(function () {

  with (this) {
    {{ender}}
    {{library}}
  }

}).call({})
```

Can somebody please explain what he is doing in a better way? I'm not quite able to follow the advantage of using the `with(this)` here, and what `{{ender}}` and `{{library}}` mean. He compares this approach to using iframes (which I understand), but I am not able to quite get what he is trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is causing all variables (and functions) declared inside that function to be inside the context of `this`, i.e. the context of the wrapping function.

Normally if you create variable using `var` inside a function it's local to that function, and that's good. But what if you don't? In that case by using `with` all variables that would otherwise be global are instead in the context of the with (in this case the context is `this` of the function.)

Comment: I tried defining a variable without the `var` keyword inside the `with` block, and it affects global scope, i.e. I am able to print that variable to console after the anonymous function has executed.

Comment: Ok got it. When you do `this.foo = 'bar'` inside the `with` block, the `foo` property is set only within the `with` block, and is not set on the global window context.